# Max current consumption of W5500 module

Tags: current

I would like to know what the max current consumption of the [W5500 module](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/W5500_datasheet_v1.0.2_1.pdf) is so I can size an appropriate voltage regulator. When I looked into the datasheet I have found something that made me second guess.

Under the absolute maximum electrical characteristics of the datasheet

[image]

It is stated that the max current consumption of this chip is 5mA, so I assumed that that is it.

but when i scrolled down I find this

[image]

[image]

So which one is it? It is written under "Power Dissipation" given with what the absolute maximum rating say, I can only surmise that that current is coming from somewhere else

Comment: this is a pretty crap datasheet, and the hardware design guide is no better (https://wizwiki.net/wiki/doku.php/design_guide:hardware:start#power_supply_gnd). From these documents, its impossible to say with certainty what the absolute maximum power draw is. I would either contact them, or, if thats impossible, design for the max typical plus 50%, although even that could be wrong. The correct thing to do here would be not to use a chip from such a crap vendor

Comment: They say here that the value is typ+10% (https://forum.wiznet.io/t/topic/3453/4) but not sure if i really trust such a half assed company

Comment: @BeB00 Sadly nothing i can really do here since this what arduinos uses, i do not know how to write my own library for a custom 100MBPS ethernet. ill just use a 300-500mA regulator then, since my digital cicuit really needs less than 10mA, 300mA regulators are cheap anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The "Absolute Maximum Ratings" are not meant to represent performance, but conditions under which the device won't break. The 5mA appears to be an input current, not a supply current...it's the amount of current you can force into an input before it fails. I think if you plan for 132mA, and specify a 200mA supply just to have some overhead, it should be fine.

Comment: Also the output currents are per output pin.  The Power Dissipation figures are the ones you need (although they actually list current rather than power).